# sortby thenby does not sort as expected

Tags: c#

I have the following code for testing purpose..

```cs
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CarNumber { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsEven { get; set; }
}

var carList = new List<Car>
{
    new Car() {CarNumber = 11, Name = "Volvo", IsEven = false, PostalCode = "12345"},
    new Car() {CarNumber = 2, Name = "Volvo", IsEven = true, PostalCode = "12345"},
    new Car() {CarNumber = 12, Name = "Volvo", IsEven = true, PostalCode = "12345"},
    new Car() {CarNumber = 14, Name = "Volvo", IsEven = true, PostalCode = "12345"}
};

foreach (var row in carList.OrderBy(x => x.PostalCode).ThenBy(y => y.IsEven == false).ThenBy(z => z.CarNumber))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{row.Name}, {row.CarNumber}, {row.PostalCode}");
}
```

When I run this it is sorted like this...

```
Volvo, 2, 12345
Volvo, 12, 12345
Volvo, 14, 12345
Volvo, 11, 12345
```

But it should be in this order instead...

```
Volvo, 11, 12345
Volvo, 2, 12345
Volvo, 12, 12345
Volvo, 14, 12345
```

Why isn't it sorted correctly?

Comment: Please note, that `false < true`, so even records will be the top ones. `.ThenBy(item => item.IsEven);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit based on comment

Replace

```
ThenBy(y => y.IsEven == false)
```

with

```
ThenBy(y => y.IsEven)
```

or

```
ThenByDescending(y => y.IsEven == false)
```

The reason is that y.IsEvent == false gives true when y.IsEvent is false, which comes later when sorting by ACS

Comment: Or `.ThenBy(y => y.IsEven)` to be rather simpler...